# Induced exact sequence on symmetric bilinear forms on abelian groups

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $F=\operatorname {Hom}(S^2(\,\_\,),\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}):\mathsf{Ab} \to \mathsf{Ab}$ be the functor that sends an abelian group to the group of symmetric bilinear forms on this group. As far as I understood, this is neither left nor right exact, but preserves epimorphisms.

However, let  $0 \to K \overset{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} G \overset{\beta}{\longrightarrow} H \to 0$ be an exact sequence of abelian groups. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4118787/176231) question (and its comments) suggest that (after dualization) there is an exact sequence induced by the Koszul complex of the symmetric algebra $R=S(G)$:
$$
0 \to F(H) \to F(G) \to \operatorname{Hom}(G\otimes K,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \to \operatorname{Alt}^2(K,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \to 0.
$$
My question is, if this is indeed true in the setting of (possibly finite) abelian groups. Unfortunately I don't really understand how this comes from the Koszul complex, so I am not sure what to check here..

Comment: I guess that you need the flatness of $K,G,H$. In this case, you first deduce the result in the case $G\simeq K\oplus H$ and both $K$ and $H$ are finite free, then animate to get the general result.

Comment: Hm, my groups are actually all finite.. is flatness really the most general setting?